# How to check that all elements of one array are greater than their counterparts in a parallel array (in Ruby).

Tags: ruby

I am trying to compare two arrays to ensure that the corresponding values of one is always greater than the other.

```
a = [2, 3, 4]
b = [1, 2, 3]

# a[0] > b[0] ... a[x] > b[x]
```

At this point I am thinking of using `inject` with an index and return if the comparison fails, like:

```
b.each_with_index.inject(true) do |cmp, (element,index)|
  if element > a[index] do
    cmp = false
    return
  end
end
```

Is there a better way of doing this? Kinda feeling like Ruby or Rails might already have something like this built-in and I missed it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what I would do:

```
 a.zip(b).all? { |a, b| a > b }
```

Note though that `zip` will truncate in case the two arrays are not of the same size.

Answer (score 5):

If it's safe to assume both arrays are of the same size, here's a method that'll keep memory usage and running time to a minimum:

```
(0...a.length).all?{ |i| a[i] > b[i] }
 #=> true
```

while also being extendable to an arbitrary number of arrays:

```
(0...a.length).all?{ |i| a[i] > [b[i], c[i], d[i]].max }
```

To illustrate the relative resource-intensity of the `zip` versus the `range` approach, take arrays `a` and `b`, each with length `n = 5_000`.

Here's the best case, where `a[0] < b[0]` is `false`:

```
             user     system      total        real
zip:     0.350000   0.000000   0.350000 (  0.351115)
range:   0.000000   0.000000   0.000000 (  0.000509)
```

and the worst, where only `a[n-1] > b[n-1]` is `false`:

```
             user     system      total        real
zip:     0.760000   0.000000   0.760000 (  0.752424)
range:   0.420000   0.000000   0.420000 (  0.421132)
```

[[Here's the benchmark script](https://gist.github.com/jmromer/9719131#file-parallel_arrays_comparison-rb)]

`zip` creates a new array out of the two (or more) you pass into it, which gets expensive for large `n`.

That said, the `zip` approach is easier to read and more idiomatic Ruby, so if scaling isn't a concern I would use that one.